# Community Builder Page Invalid when Passing Parameter

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community-builder

I have a custom Community Builder page that is a custom "Standard Detail" page called "TransactionDetail" (i.e. a detail, list, and related list page were each created).  I have a component I added to the page that takes a recordId in the design file, which I set to {!recordId} in the community builder.

When I try to navigate to this page, and pass an Id, the page shows Invalid Page and does not load anything.  When I remove the parameter, and just navigate to /s/transactiondetail, the header for the page shows up as expected.

Here's what I'm using to navigate to the page (the URL ends up looking exactly how I want it to):

```
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    navEvt.setParams({
        "url" : "/transactiondetail/"+srcId,
        "isredirect" :false
    });
    navEvt.fire();
```

The URL I end up navigating to looks like "/s/transactiondetail/[recordid]" just as I would expect, however it just shows Invalid Page.  I commented out all of the custom code and just have "test" displaying in the component itself, so there's no code causing an error in the component itself.

I also tried creating a non-standard custom community page and adding the component, it gives the same result.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Disregard, I found that it was profile access issues.  When accessing a detail page override, the logged in user's profile is checked before attempting to load any data or elements into the view.